# KENDO WINDOW WITH URL CONTENT

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a kendo window with URL CONTENT and I want it to hide scrollbar or overflow hidden. I also search in internet and I have found this

```
.k-window  div.k-window-content
{
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

but it's not working when kendo window has a content with URL. Is there anyway to hide that scroll bar? scrollbar: false also not working. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Please use only the WIndow's ID instead of the CSS selector.

```
  #windowId
{
        overflow: hidden;
}
```

It's work for me.